# Make excel relate to different values

Tags: microsoft-excel, automation

I have an excel-file with 3 spreadsheets. On page two and three I have a huge list of IP addresses which all relate to a specific name which can be found on both page two and three.

I want to type in the name on page one, lets say "Marketing" and then I want to get the "Marketing" IP-adresses in 2 cells below. This "Marketing, can be found on both pages with unique IP adresses.

Comment: So what is your question? On what part are you stuck?

Comment: Id say on the startingpoint... I have no clue how to do what I'm asking for. I want page 1 to print values from page 2 and 3, related to a "Name" that exist on page 2 and 3

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is usually done using lookup functions like vlookup or hlookup. Here's a  [tutorial](http://youtu.be/-hJxIMBbmZY) for it.

Comment: The problem with your answer is link only answers go bad (links die etc). It is totally cool to copy the relevant part of their answer into your post and cite the website as a reference :)

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment on your post, VLookUp will probably do, but I don't know Excel functions so this does the job using VBa.

```
Sub search()

Dim searchValue As String
searchValue = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value = GetIpFromWorksheet("Sheet2", searchValue)
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value = GetIpFromWorksheet("Sheet3", searchValue)

End Sub

Public Function GetIpFromWorksheet(ByVal sheet As String, ByVal search As String) As String

Dim row As Integer
row = 1

Do While (True)

    If Worksheets(sheet).Range("A" & row).Value = "" Then
        GetIpFromWorksheet = "Not found"
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Worksheets(sheet).Range("A" & row).Value = search Then
        GetIpFromWorksheet = Worksheets(sheet).Range("B" & row).Value
        Exit Function
    End If

    row = row + 1


Loop

End Function
```

Sheet1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Sheet3:

[image]

Sheet1 after I click the search button

[image]